# How to rotate 2x3 matrix?

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations

For `2x2` matrix for example:
$$K_1 = \pmatrix{K_{xx} \quad K_{xy}\\
               K_{yx} \quad K_{yy}}$$
 the transformation matrix is:
    $$ A = \pmatrix {\cos \theta \qquad \sin \theta\\
                \!\!-\sin \theta \qquad \!\!\cos \theta}$$

the above matrix is for rotation in counterclockwise direction, suppose I have a `2x3` matrix for example:
$$K_2 = \pmatrix{K_{xxx}  \quad K_{xxy} \quad K_{xyy}\\
           K_{yxx}  \quad K_{yxy} \quad K_{yyy}}$$ what will be the transformation matrix? and how can I transform the above matrix by, let say $30^\circ$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define "rotate a matrix."

Comment: @Batominovski Actually $K_1, K_2$ are stiffness matrices in classical Cartesian coordinate (positive x-axis on the right and positive y-axis on the top), I need to use the precious matrices in different coordinate rotated by an angle $\theta$.

Comment: For $K_1$ the new rotated matrix can be obtained by using the transformation matrix $A$ and by applying the below formula $$New K_1 = A^T K_1 A$$For $K_2$ what will be the transformation matrix?

Comment: A rotation matrix $R$ is called a *"rotation matrix"* because when you multiply it by a *vector* $x$, the result $Rx$ is what you would get from rotating the associated point $x$ in space about the origin by a certain angle.  It doesn't immediately make sense to talk about "rotating a matrix".

Comment: How do you intend to end up with a non-square stiffness matrix?

Comment: So, your new $K_1$ is basically the transformation $K_1$ with respect to a new basis rotated by $A$.  However, $K_2$ is not a linear transformation on the same vector space.  You need to have two rotations, or there is no point of this discussion.

Comment: You are right $K_2$ is non-linear, is there any way to rotate it as in $New K_1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I might not be clear in explanation what I want, I want to rotate the elements of the matrix (points) by an angle.

Comment: The elements of the matrix are numbers.  It doesn't make sense to rotate a number, it only makes sense to rotate a vector.

Comment: $K_2$ is a linear transformation, but not on the same vector space, unlike $K_1$, which is a linear transformation on the same vector space.  $K_1$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself, but $K_2$ maps $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So, if you want to make some kind of rotations on $K_2$, you have to rotate a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, say, using a $2$-by-$2$ rotation matrix $X$, and you also have to rotate a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, say, using a $3$-by-$3$ special orthogonal matrix $Y$.  Then, $X^\top K_2 Y$ is probably the new $K_2$ you want.

Comment: If you really want to make the same kind of change to a $2 \times 3$ matrix,  you should take $A$ to be a $3 \times 2$ matrix.  It's not clear what matrix $A$ would be meaningful here, since it's not clear how one should extend the notion of rotation matrices to allow for non-square rotation matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it must be $3 \times 2$ matrix, but what are the values of the new extend elements?

Comment: @Batominovski thanks for the explanation. How could I get the special matrix $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Is your stiffness matrix having some formula like the $ D $ operator defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness_matrix#Practical_assembly_of_the_stiffness_matrix? In that case, it suggests a formula: each column will rotate like a vector. So you will have $ K' = A K $.

Regrettably, I am missing some context and particularly I don't know what a stiffness matrix is. But your answer will be found by understanding what the domain and range of $ K $ are; or in other words, understanding the physical meaning of the matrix. Suppose $ K: V \rightarrow W $, and a rotation $ R $ acts on $ V $ by matrix $ R_v $ and on $ W $ by a matrix $ R_w $, then the transformation for $ K $ is $ R_w K R_v^{-1} $.

Comment: what is the form of $A$, and can I apply this method for `3x2` matrix?

Comment: $ A $ transforms like $ K $.

Comment: I guess it will equal to $$\pmatrix{-\sin\theta \quad -\cos\theta \\ \cos\theta \quad - \sin\theta}$$

Comment: for `3x2` matrix, is it in the same way or not?